# How to store a record in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, record

Here is what i am trying to do. I am getting 3 user inputs from the user(name, age and gender) and all these inputs are one record. For example name=John, age= 15, gender= M , this is the record of the person named John.

I am trying to make 5 records like the example above and i am trying to store it to an array. The problem is i am not aware of how to do it.

Here is what i have done so far :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define Max 40


struct person{

    char name[Max];
    int age;
    char gender;

};

void inputdetails(struct person *,struct person []);

main()
{

struct person students[5]; //created an array type person to store the records

    struct person k;
    inputdetails(&k,students); //passed the array in to the input details function

}

void inputdetails(struct person *q,struct person hello[])
{
    int i=0;

    for(;i<5;i++)
    {
    printf("Enter name\n");
        gets(q->name);

    printf("Enter age\n");
    scanf("%d",&(q->age));

        fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter gender\n");
    scanf("%c",&(q->gender));  


}

}
```

How do i do this ? How can i store 1 whole record in to the array,so when i make a function to display the records , i can just give an index number so it will display the record stored in that index?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `for` loop into `main`, like this:

```
int main() {
    struct person students[5]; //created an array type person to store the records
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
        inputdetails(&students[i], i);
    }
    return 0;
}
void inputdetails(struct person *q, int pos) {
    // Put all the data into q->...
    printf("Enter name of student %d\n", pos);
    // Do not use gets(), it's a security hazard
    scanf("%39s", q->name);
    ...
}
```

Your current implementation creates an unnecessary `struct person k`, and runs the loop inside the `inputdetails` function. An assumption is made that the second argument points to an array of size five. Finally, inside the loop you keep re-assigning the elements of the same temporary `struct` (which points to `k` inside `main()`, which is why the `students` does not get filled.

I changed `inputdetails` to read a single entry at a time. Now `main()` is in charge of where the data is placed: it passes a pointer to each element of `students[]` in turn, along with the sequence number of the student for printing purposes.

Comment: i didn't really get what you are trying to say. Can you explain a bit more? 

Thank you.

Comment: @Shehan.W I edited the answer, see if the explanation makes things cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure and array declarations are correct. (Note: I assume you have an input details similar to what dasblinkenlight has shown above.)

To scan a single element of the array (for example, the first element of the array), use

```
inputdetails(&students[0], int pos);
```

To scan all the elements of the array, use a loop of the form

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    inputdetails(&students[i], i);
}
```

Hope that helps.